# How to assign values to multiple columns using conditions for values from other multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Dataset is something like this (there will be duplicate rows in the original):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_in = pd.DataFrame({'email_ID': {0: 'mail_1',
  1: 'mail_1',
  2: 'mail_1',
  3: 'mail_1',
  4: 'mail_1',
  5: 'mail_1',
  6: 'mail_2',
  7: 'mail_2',
  8: 'mail_2',
  9: 'mail_2',
  10: 'mail_2',
  11: 'mail_2'},
 'time_stamp': {0: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.340259',
  1: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.672814',
  2: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.471423',
  3: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.480891',
  4: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.484644',
  5: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.984644',
  6: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.340259',
  7: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.672814',
  8: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.471423',
  9: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.480891',
  10: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.484644',
  11: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.984644'},
 'screen': {0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'c',
  5: 'b',
  6: 'a',
  7: 'b',
  8: 'c',
  9: 'b',
  10: 'c',
  11: 'd'}})

df_in['time_stamp'] = df_in['time_stamp'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df_in
```

Output should be this:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_out = pd.DataFrame({'email_ID': {0: 'mail_1',
  1: 'mail_1',
  2: 'mail_1',
  3: 'mail_1',
  4: 'mail_1',
  5: 'mail_1',
  6: 'mail_2',
  7: 'mail_2',
  8: 'mail_2',
  9: 'mail_2',
  10: 'mail_2',
  11: 'mail_2'},
 'time_stamp': {0: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.340259',
  1: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.672814',
  2: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.471423',
  3: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.480891',
  4: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.484644',
  5: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.984644',
  6: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.340259',
  7: '2021-09-10 09:01:56.672814',
  8: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.471423',
  9: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.480891',
  10: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.484644',
  11: '2021-09-10 09:01:57.984644'},
 'screen': {0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  3: 'd',
  4: 'c',
  5: 'b',
  6: 'a',
  7: 'b',
  8: 'c',
  9: 'b',
  10: 'c',
  11: 'd'},
 'series1': {0: 0,
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 0,
  5: 1,
  6: 0,
  7: 1,
  8: 2,
  9: 3,
  10: 4,
  11: 5},
 'series2': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 1,
  5: 1,
  6: 2,
  7: 2,
  8: 2,
  9: 2,
  10: 2,
  11: 2}})

df_out['time_stamp'] = df['time_stamp'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

df_out
```

'series1' column values starts row by row as 0, 1, 2, and so on but resets to 0 when:

1. 'email_ID' column value changes.
2. 'screen' column value == 'd'

'series2' column values starts with 0 and increments by 1 whenever 'series1' resets.

My progress:

```
series1 = [0]

x = 0

for index in df[1:].index:

  if ((df._get_value(index - 1, 'email_ID')) == df._get_value(index, 'email_ID')) and (df._get_value(index - 1, 'screen') != 'd'):

    x += 1

    series1.append(x)
  
  else:
    x = 0

    series1.append(x)


df['series1'] = series1
df

series2 = [0]

x = 0

for index in df[1:].index:

  if df._get_value(index, 'series1') - df._get_value(index - 1, 'series1') == 1:

    series2.append(x)
  
  else:
    
    x += 1

    series2.append(x)


df['series2'] = series2
df
```

I think the code above is working, I'll test answered codes and select the best in a few hours, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
m = df_in['screen']=='d'
df_in['pf'] = np.where(m, 1, np.nan)
df_in.loc[m, 'pf'] = df_in[m].cumsum()
grouper = df_in.groupby('email_ID')['pf'].bfill()
df_in['series1'] = df_in.groupby(grouper).cumcount()
df_in['series2'] = df_in.groupby(grouper.fillna(0), sort=False).ngroup()
df_in.drop('pf', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Explanation:

- First locate the rows where 'screen' is 'd' and then use `cumsum()` to identify their numbers.
  This is accomplished by:

```py
  df_in['pf'] = np.where(m, 1, np.nan)
  df_in.loc[m, 'pf'] = df_in[m].cumsum()
```

- Then use `bfill` to backfill the NaN values with the positions where 'screen' shows 'd'. This will ensure the above rows are of the same group, but do it per email_ID. This is accomplished by:

```py
  grouper = df_in.groupby('email_ID')['pf'].bfill()
```

- Then it is straightforward to see that once you define a grouper, you can use `cumcount` to get the `series1` column. This is done by:

```py
  df_in['series1'] = df_in.groupby(grouper).cumcount()
```

- Then get `series2` column by using [`ngroup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html). But make sure the groupby is done with `sort=False`. Done by:

```py
  df_in['series2'] = df_in.groupby(grouper.fillna(0), sort=False).ngroup()
```

- Finally drop the unwanted column `pf`.

```py
  df_in.drop('pf', axis=1, inplace=True)
```